# How to get values from two tables in which one column in each table contains similar value?

Tags: android, mysql

I have two tables the queries are given below

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS allquestions (num_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, questions TEXT NOT NULL,catogery TEXT NOT NULL,age INT NOT NULL)" );
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS answers (num_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,questionid INT NOT NULL,answer TEXT NOT NULL)" );
```

[image]

Here the num_id in allqestions contains the question number and the answers are there in the table(answers) column answer.In the answer column the questionid contains the question number for the answer.So what I want is how to write the query to get  questions from allquestion and its answers from table answer.

Comment: And your expected output format ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty a column having Question and its three answers next questions its three answers like that..

Comment: You can not have 3 answers in three columns knowing the fact that the answers could be unknown, however they could be arranged in a single column with comma separated string if this needs to be done via sql.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty What i am looking is to set question in a textview and its three answers in checkbox.So if i get(in array) first question  in 0th postion and its answers in 1st,2nd and 3rd.4th position contains second question and its answers in 5th,6th,7th position in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need it.

```
select questions,answers from questions que,answers ans where que.num_id=ans.questionid;
```

Comment: @PareshMayani ya it was around something i was looking for...except the question getting repeated.if (c.moveToFirst()) {
   do { 

  use1= new Use();
  use1.question=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("questions"));
  use1.ans=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("answer"));
 
   UseList.add(use1);
  
   } while (c.moveToNext());
   
  }  .One question and its answers,another question its answeers

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply the join on both tables.

```
       SELECT 
      allquestions.`num_id`,allquestions.`questions`,answers.questionid,
       answers.answer from allquestions  JOIN answers ON allquestions.`num_id`
         = answers.questionid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. I hope you are looking for the same.
Give a row_number for each group, then use a `CASE` statement.

**Query**

```
select t1.questionid,a.questions,
max(case when t1.row_number=1 then t1.answer else 0 end) as answer1,
max(case when t1.row_number=2 then t1.answer else 0 end) as answer2,
max(case when t1.row_number=3 then t1.answer else 0 end) as answer3
from allquestions a
join (
SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @questionid=questionid 
THEN @row_number+1 
ELSE 1 
END AS row_number,
@questionid:=questionid AS questionid,answer
FROM answers, 
(SELECT @row_number:=0,@questionid:='') AS t
ORDER BY questionid
)t1
on a.num_id=t1.questionid
group by t1.questionid;
```

[Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64f9d/1)